How to overwrite a thrid party block's css in a child theme?
Consider a Wordpress (6.6) child theme based on the default Twenty Twenty Four theme: How do you style form fields used in third party blocks?
Just copy and pasting a modified version of the third party block's css to the child theme's style.css file does not show any effect.
And according to this issue , form fields can't be styled through theme.json.
Question now is, if  you're unhappy with the looks of a third party contact form, how can you overwrite its styles?
Edit:
Here's some original css from the third party block (Form block of CoBlocks) whose style should be changed:
.coblocks-form .coblocks-field,
.coblocks-form select {
  margin:0 0 1.25rem;
  width:100%
}

According to Firefox's dev tools, it's the last style that's getting applied to the form's text input fields. Changing it to something obviously different like...
.coblocks-form .coblocks-field,
.coblocks-form select {
  color: green;
  background-color: pink;
  margin:0 0 1.25rem;
  width:100%
}

...and placing it at the child theme's style.css, has unfortunately no effect. Question now is, where does the changed css needs to be placed to ensure it's getting applied?
Any advise is welcome. Thank you.

The original CSS doesn't betray any special specificity, if what you posted is exactly what the rule is. So, the first thing you could do is add the "!important" flag after any one of the declarations in your child theme stylesheet and re-upload it. If your desired change takes effect, that would indicate that you need to enqueue your child theme stylesheet AFTER the parent theme's stylesheet.

It would be of advantage if you post code to your problem. A concrete line of CSS with some context of the current Blocks in place?
First, you have to check which CSS is responsible for the look. You wrote child-theme TwentyTwentyFour but Third-Party-Plugins?
After that it is just a matter of specificity of the CSS-selektor and where you need to put it in place.
Usually, CSS can be added to the child-theme (head, inline, theme.json).
In case it is the CSS of the block/third-party-plugin, then this documentation is the one where to dig for a solution.

Thanks for your help.  Question updated.  "... where you need to put it in place" is what it boils down to.
